# jQuery-validation errorlabel template

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to wrap the error label with this template, but without success.
(http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
    <div class="fx-alert-icon">
        <i class="fxicons fxicons-error"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="fx-alert-desc">
        <label id="input-error" class="has-error" for="input1">
            Input with error!!
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

One solution is to change the `errorElement` and then in the method `showErrors()` change the `message`, but i don't feel comfortable with this solution...

```
var errMsgTmpl = '<div class="alert alert-error">' +
                 '<div class="fx-alert-icon">' +
                 ' <i class="fxicons fxicons-error"></i>' +
                 '</div>' +
                 '<div class="fx-alert-desc"><label for="{{LABEL-FOR}}">{{ERROR-MSG}}</label></div>' +
                 '</div>';

$.validator.setDefaults({            
    errorElement: "section", 
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        var i, elements;
        for (i = 0; errorList[i]; i++) {
            errorList[i].message = errMsgTmpl
            .replace(/{{ERROR-MSG}}/, errorList[i].message)
            .replace(/{{LABEL-FOR}}/, $(errorList[i].element).attr('id'));
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
});
```

At this moment i have the layout working without the template, using only css, but at some point my message could be more complex, and i think the use of a template is the best option.

Comment: The `showErrors` callback option is used for creating a message summary box, not for customizing the individual messages.

Comment: Thank you @Sparky, some idea how can i customize the individual message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to wrap the error label with this template, but without success.

You would not wrap the element within a template.  You would put this structure within your page and then use the plugin to dynamically insert the error message element into it.

You have not stated where you want this new structure to appear with respect to the `input`, so I cannot work out the proper DOM traversal techniques.  The default `label` element is placed *after* the `input`.

Regardless, you would apply various jQuery DOM traversal methods like `.parents()`, `.closest()`, `.siblings()`, `.next()`, etc. to the `element` object to inject the `<label>` element (`error` object) exactly within your desired structure.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

Comment: if i understand your suggestion using the `errorPlacement` i put the error message inside my template and then i should capture the `highlight` and `unhighlight` methods in order to show or hide the template that holds the error message?

Comment: @NunoSantos, yes, the `highlight` and `unhighlight` methods can also be used along with this.  They will automatically be fired when the messages need to be toggled.  However, only put the *structure* within your HTML... then allow the plugin to automatically insert the error message `label` as per your code within the `errorPlacement` callback.